# Good search engine friendly e-commerce platform on Microsoft technology

Tags: seo, ecommerce, microsoft

I'm looking for a good search engine friendly e-commerce platform built on microsoft technology. I know that Magento is maybe the best choice if you are on a LAMP stack but now i'm forced to make my choice in the Microsoft realm.

Here's some candidates platform that seems to integrate some search engine friendly features:

- ASPdotNet Storefron
- Znode
- Able Commerce

Anyone have experience with them or can suggest other candidates?

Comment: "CMS" to me means "Content Management System", i.e. article-, image- & video-publication system, but not shopping cart / ecommerce solution. Would you consider revising your tags and heading?

Comment: @Jasper I agree, I edited the question to be more focused on e-commerce solution

Comment: The majority of comments I've read about ASPDotNet storefront have been very negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) is rather nice, has many built in SEO feature, plus is open source so you can customize as needed. Very feature rich and has recently release .NET 4.0 version. Not positive if making use of the routing engine, but could extend rather easily I am sure.

Comment: We haven't actually built a site on NOPCommerce yet but it does look like a very nice all around E-Commerce Solution and I was impressed with its SEO friendliness.

Answer (score 1):

I use Able, and am very pleased with it.  The CommerceBuilder architecture allows you to easily create and implement your own UserControls if you're into that sort of thing.

As far as the SEO aspect goes, Able sites use a keyword rich product URL which is nice, and you also have the ability to specify a canonical URL.  One thing to note is that the URL rewrite uses the product name, so if you change the name that could present an issue, especially with well indexed urls.  Though, with Able, there is also a tutorial on how to implement your own URL rewrite scheme, so you can always change it if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: AbleCommerce is a very solid offering overall. Very well written code. We had to make some customizations to make it easy for clients to specify the Title but otherwise we're happy with it's SEO Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Kentico](http://www.kentico.com/home.aspx) in the past. It's well supported and generates SEO friendly pages. It generates URLs from the page titles and doesn't use parameters [from here](http://www.kentico.com/getdoc/32a58a34-7ccf-405b-9683-c2d77ba217f5/Friendly-URLs-and-SEO.aspx). It also has [e-commerce support](http://www.kentico.com/getdoc/1f25e79d-957b-439b-9ea7-6bb1843b6838/E-commerce.aspx).